# How to define a Uniform Type Identifier in a plist file?

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, mime-types, uti

My application uses the following `NSApplicationDelegate` function.

```
- (void)application:(NSApplication*)sender openFiles:(NSArray*)filenames;
```

I want to use this function to enable the user to drag and drop **image files** onto the application icon in the dock.

How do I have to define certain file types in my `plist` file to restrict them to be images? I found out the structure has to look something like this.

```
// plist file contents taken from Preview.app
[...]
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>jpeg.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
        <true/>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
        <string>PVDocument</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I added it to the `plist` file but it does not work. A popup window shows the following error message.

> The document "test.jpg" could not be opened. MyApp cannot open files
>   in the "JPEG image" format.

Further, I read [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE) that there is `public.image` which would be what I want to define.

Meanwhile, I found out that the `plist` file only contains the key `CFBundleDocumentTypes` if I create a Cocoa Application with the option "Create document-based application.". Can you please clarify what dependencies exist for the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>png</string>
                <string>jpg</string>
                            ... add as many types as you need
            </array>
                    ... other keys
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Update: The CFBundleDocumentTypes key is deprecated in Mac OS X v10.5. The new key LSItemContentTypes should be used instead. The items are UTI strings:

```
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>public.png</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) Are the types case-sensitive; in other words: do I need to add "PNG" and "JPG" and mixed variations as well? (2) Do you know why they do not use the UTI scheme (reverse DNS) here?

Comment: Sorry, the information was outdated. CFBundleDocumentTypes still works, but has been deprecated. (1) Is is case insensitive (2) See the update.

Comment: Same error message. The `dict` element only contains `CFBundleTypeRole` and `CFBundleTypeExtensions` with values as suggested - but still it does not work.

Comment: Meanwhile, I created a new clean project and edited the plist as you suggest. It works. So the problem must be somewhere else .-(

Comment: The difference may be if MyApp is a document based application, but the new clean project is not. I see you use PVDocument class in you plist. In this case you do not need to implement [NSApplicationDelegate application: openFiles:], but [NSDocument readFromFileWrapper: ofType: error:] in your PVDocument subclass.

Comment: No. The plist in my first post is taken from Preview.app - it was just an example. And yes - I left `NSDocumentClass` out. Secondly, my clean new test application is no document-based application. To repeat myself - this clean new test application works. But the real application does not.

Comment: I found the error somewhere else. I called a method in the `init`-method of an object. The method itself used self which has not been fully initialized in the middle of the `init`. - Thank you for you patience. I edited your post to add the full xml definition that works for me. - Interesting enough: `public.image` as a general definition does not work.

Answer (score -1):

If your document types are common types, you could use `UTI's`
[About UTI's](http://www.escape.gr/manuals/qdrop/UTI.html)

Comment: sorry but it is a dead link