# iPhone: image file extensions doesn't associate to my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, file-extension

I'm trying to associate my iPhone application to open image files such as jpeg and png. I did it this way:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But this solution doesn't work. If I replace *public.image* with, for example, *public.objective-c-source* my app begins to open objective-c source code. But when I use *public.image* or *public.jpeg* it doesn't work.

Can you tell where is my mistake? Thank you for answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197757/why-cant-i-register-my-ios-application-to-handle-the-image-file-type   - Looks like you cannot really open an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [question in apple developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/140939?tstart=0) (You need to login to devforums.apple.com to see this link), it is not possible. The reason mentioned there is as follows,

> Not allowed, it means you will high jack the default behavior of the
>   iOS camera & photo app. Register a file type unique to your app.