# Opening a jpeg image from mail app into my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was trying to implement this functionallity for the first time, and seemed pretty straight forward, but for some reason is not working for me.

My intention is to open a simple jpeg from the mail app into my application, after that was not working I was just trying to open any kind of document by adding this to the Info.plist.

Same result, my application is not appearing on the list of "Open with..."

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key> <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>All Docs</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
    </dict>  </array>
```

I have search already in StackOverFlow and the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html), but none of the answers make it work for me, so maybe is something simple that I am missing here...

[Why is my iOS app not showing up in other apps' "Open in" dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266079/why-is-my-ios-app-not-showing-up-in-other-apps-open-in-dialog)

[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290)

**How I am testing it (maybe has to do with this):**

Have an email with an attachment. Add the settings to the plist and the run the application on my device, hoping that the next time I open the mail app and click on the attachment my app will be on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that is not possible. At least to provide a custom way to open images **from the mail app**. There is no problem if is from another place, but apple has limited the options on the mail app so we would use the "copy" option as a workaround.

Update:
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197757/why-cant-i-register-my-ios-application-to-handle-the-image-file-type?rq=1) goes in the same direction.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to open images from the mail app, it's just somewhat convoluted:

Tap and hold the image.
Tap on Quick Look so the image goes fullscreen.
Tap the image to show the top toolbar.
Tap the open in button at the top right.
Scroll the list to the left to find your app.

Comment: Can please let me know what type should provide in plist like public.content for images ?

Comment: I have tried but that doesn't help. . Can you please post the code(.plist) to achieve the functionality. . Here i have posted my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108450/how-to-add-the-application-in-open-with-or-share-with-in-photos-image . Please check it and advice. . Looking forward your reply. .