# How to add the application in "Open with or Share with " in Photos image?

Tags: ios, ios7

I would like to add the application icon in the image "Open with" as like the below image :

[image]

I have implement the below code to add the "Open with" in the document but for the image it doesn't work.

```
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Unknown File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.content </string>
        </array>
</dict>
```

Public.content is adding the "open with" in all the applications.

Public.image is not adding in the "Open with". As per Xcode 5 i have modified the document type in info as per the below screen shot.

Can please let me know what type of parameter should add the app icon in "Open with" ?

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Comment: please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991990/my-app-inside-imessage-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: @Popeye In xcode IDE , Project Targets -> Info -> Document Types. I have did anything wrong here or is it possible to configure using Xcode ?

Comment: @ManojArunS This has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` just because you are using the `xcode IDE` doesn't mean you should use the tag, so please don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it is *not possible* to add your app to the share dialog of the Photos
application (even if your app is correctly configured to support all kinds of image types
or general content).

To get photos into your application, you have to go the other way around and use an
`UIImagePickerController` or the `ALAssetsLibrary` to *fetch* the photos.

Comment: Is there any apple document to clarify this ?  How Facebook and Twitter icon added here ?  Can you please advice ?

Comment: @ManojArunS: Sorry, I did not find official documentation, it is the result of my own research. Facebook and Twitter support is "built-in" into iOS. I have have never seen *any* 3rd-party app in the photo share dialog. Dropbox does it the same way: There is a photo selection dialog in the Dropbox app.

Comment: There are many more apps now showing up there including not "A" apps like easyJet and Upwork.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this tutorial](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog-tags/ios?page=1)

and goto **Sharing with UIActivityViewController** it shows how to add Google+ app in `UIActivityViewController`, so you can add your app too.

Comment: Can you please provide the username and pwd to access the tutorial ?

Comment: I've provide iOS home page url from the site, just click on first link ie. Sharing with UIActivityViewController. i did not require to login.

Comment: Are you able to access link?

Comment: Yes. . Thanks. . But I would like to add the 3rd party application in the Photos Gallery "Open With" not in the Application . . Is it possible ? Can you please advice ?